# Webbrowser Source Is Empty

Tags: c#

```
public async void ScrapeBing()
        {
            TabPage tab = new TabPage();
            tab.Text = "Bing";
            tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab);
            bingTab = new WebBrowser();
            bingTab.Parent = tab;
            bingTab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            for (int j = 0; j < urlList.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                bingTab.Navigate("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + urlList.Items[j].ToString());
                await PageLoad(30, 5, bingTab);
                string pageSource = this.bingTab.DocumentText.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(pageSource);
                string regexExpression = "(?<=<li class=\"b_algo\"><h2><a href=\")(.*?)(?=\" h=\"ID=SERP)";
                Regex match = new Regex(regexExpression, RegexOptions.Singleline);
                MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(pageSource, regexExpression);
                MessageBox.Show(collection.Count.ToString());
                for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
                {
                    CommonCodes.WriteToTxt(collection[i].ToString(), "bingscrapedurls.txt");
                    MessageBox.Show(collection[i].ToString());
                }

                while (true)
                {

                    if (bingTab.DocumentText.Contains("=\"sb_pagN sb_pagN_bp b_widePag sb_bp \" title=\"Next page\" href=\""))
                    {
                        string nextLinkRegex = "(?<=\" title = \"Next page\" href = \")(.*?)(?=\" h = \")";
                        Regex rg = new Regex(nextLinkRegex);
                        string nextpgUrl = rg.Match(bingTab.DocumentText).ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(nextpgUrl.ToString());
                        bingTab.Navigate("https://www.bing.com" + nextpgUrl);
                        await PageLoad(30, 5, bingTab);
                        ScrapePages(bingTab.DocumentText, "(?<==\"b_algo\"><h2><a href=\"><a href=\")(.*?)(?=\" h = \"ID=SERP)", "bingscrapedurls.txt");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if (j == urlList.Items.Count - 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("URL's Scraped.");
                }

            }
        }
```

---

PageLoad Method:

```
private async Task PageLoad(int TimeOut, int delay, WebBrowser w)
        {
            try
            {
                TaskCompletionSource<bool> PageLoaded = null;
                PageLoaded = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                int TimeElapsed = 0;
                w.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (w.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) return;
                    if (PageLoaded.Task.IsCompleted) return; PageLoaded.SetResult(true);
                };
                //
                while (PageLoaded.Task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(delay * 1000);//interval of 10 ms worked good for me
                    TimeElapsed++;
                    if (TimeElapsed >= TimeOut * 100) PageLoaded.TrySetResult(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CommonCodes.WriteLog(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

### }

I have applied the same code for google.com page its working perfectly while I am using the code for bing.com its giving empty source at the line

```
string pageSource = this.bingTab.DocumentText.ToString();`
```

### --

Any Idea? Thank you. I tried DocumentStream too no use. Not sure why this is happening. ScrapBing Method will scrape urls from the bing webpages and PageLoad is the Method to wait until the page load completed.

Comment: Check the HTTP headers coming from Bing. It might have sent a redirect or error header with a  blank page.  Also, does your demo UI look like it loaded any content for Bing?

Comment: Yes the browser is showing the bing page perfectly! The issue was fixed automatically after restarting the pc. I don't know how it was fixed. Thanks any way.